# upstart start job with delay after another job was started and is running

Tags: java, ubuntu, solr, init, upstart

I'm trying to use upstart for the first time. I have two java programs that i want to start. The first one is a solr search server running on jetty, and the second one is a custom crawler that should start after the solr server started.

my crawler init script looks like this:

```
description     "crawler"
author ""

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

script
    cd /home/crawler
    java -Duser.timezone=Europe/Berlin  -jar crawler.jar
end script
```

Now for the solr server i wrote this:

```
description     "server"

start on starting crawler
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

script
    cd /home/server/version0.1/example
    java -Duser.language=en -Dsolr.clustering.enabled=true -Duser.country=US  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar start.jar
end script
```

both get started so it seems to work, but i want the crawler to be started after a little delay of say 2 seconds, to give the server time to enable everything. 
Anyone knows how to do this?
What do you think about the two upstart scripts are they okay or did i miss something? (I'm a total init noob)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace **starting** with **started**

```
start on started crawler
```

Comment: and what's a syntax for stop? `stop on stopped crawler` ?

Comment: should work, why don't you try it? read http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/ and http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html 
6.33.2   Stop before depended-upon service `stop on stopping other-service`
6.33.3   Stop after dependent service `stop on stopped other-service`

Answer (score 1):

I think adding a `sleep 2` will pause the script for a 2 seconds and should be a solution.